# Correct way of setting up UINavigationController and its RootViewController in IB

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

I have the following structure in my iPad App:

- Application

  - `UINavigationController` (Providing the top bar with `UIBarButton`s etc.)

    - Initial Login screen
    - Second login screen

I am not sure how I should now set this up in Interfacebuilder correctly. My guess would be that I create two ViewControllers:

1. `LoginVC1`: (This one should also include the NavigationController since it is the first of the two screens)
2. `LoginVC2`: Based on some delegate callback from `LoginVC1` my application would push to this ViewController.

This is my `LoginVC1` in IB:
[LoginVC1 http://k.minus.com/jpamEAFkBjpKT.png](http://k.minus.com/jpamEAFkBjpKT.png)

And when I present it modally it looks like this which is not what I want:
[Result http://k.minus.com/jHAYRnY788jFt.png](http://k.minus.com/jHAYRnY788jFt.png)

The result:

- Nor the title of the ViewController nor the Cancel button is shown
- The view seems to be empty despite my view in IB
- I have set the Presentation mode of the `UINavigationController` to `FormSheet` which is ignored too since it is displayed in fullscreen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe I should just have posted the two images with the text "Find the error" :-)

Comment: Have you set the `rootViewController` as navigationBarController?

Comment: @Kjuly I simply do `presentModalViewController` to show the dialog, but since my UINavigationControler contains a UIViewController (See nib-screen), I would assume that this ViewController is displayed when the modal is shown.

Comment: The message I missed?! I'm so sorry.. Have you solved it yet? Maybe you should accept @CodaFi's answer. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Kjuly I simply do presentModalViewController to show the dialog, but
>   since my UINavigationControler contains a UIViewController (See
>   nib-screen), I would assume that this ViewController is displayed when
>   the modal is shown.

Not always Besi.  Adding it to the UINavigationController Hierarchy doesn't add is as the rootViewController.  That must be done in code like this:

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[ExamplesViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
```

Also, check that you are presenting the NavigationController, and not the ViewController modally.

To solve the NavigationBar title issue, try setting the `self.title` property in the

`-(void)viewDidload` method and see if that works.  If not, try `self.//instance of UINavigationController//.navigationBar.title = @"string"`.

As for the other buttons not showing up, my guess is that if setting the root controller in code doesn't help, then you only made reference to them in the .h, instead of instantiating them.  So either call something like this in the .h:

```
//.h
@implementation ExampleViewController: UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

     IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem * CancelButton;
     IBOutlet UITextField * usernameField;
     IBOutlet UITextField * passwordField;
     IBOutlet UIButton * loginButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem * CancelButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * usernameField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * passwordField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton * loginButton;
```

Then connect the outlets in the XIB, or instantiate the buttons in the .m with:

```
//.m 

-(void)viewDidLoad {

//do stuff
    CancelButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissSelf)]autorelease];

//do more stuff

}
```